# SSH.NET How to return a boolean from command execution

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am new to the SSH.NET library and I understand the basics of it such as connecting, executing a command and returning the output.

But my question is, how can I return a true/false statement if I wanted to check if a background process is running or not?

So for example:

```
  using (SshClient client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
  {
      client.Connect();
      var cmd = client.RunCommand("uname -sn");
      string serverResponse = cmd.Result;
      Label1.Text = serverResponse;
      client.Disconnect();
  }
```

So if I wanted to replace my command with "ps -u user | grep procName" I would like to have it tell me yes or no if said procName is running.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Just check the exit status of the command object.  grep will exit with code 0 if it finds the search pattern.  Example: if (cmd.ExitStatus == 0) { DoStuff(); }

Comment: That wouldn't work because it will always return true with a grep... Even if I  use the ExitStatus, it's going to exit with 0 because it sees the procname in the grep command.

Comment: Then use another grep command to exclude the grep commands e.g. "ps -u user | grep procName | grep -v grep"